# ssl installation on apache ubuntu16.0.4

Tags: apache, ssl, laravel-5.4, ubuntu-16.04

My hosting (instance) is on EC2 and domain is on Nominalia. I am using ubuntu16.0.4 and Laravel 5.4, I have generated CSR, key file, certificate file and kept on root of server that is /var/www/html

Now I have to place

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/sitename.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/sitename.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/html/intermediate-ca.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

I am not getting where I shall keep it. I tried to keep in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf or /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf or /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf but it did not work and I am getting errors

In chrome

> This site can’t be reached

and in Mozilla

> Secure Connection Failed

Site is working without https

I also tried to keep both "VirtualHost *:443" and "VirtualHost *:80" in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf but it also did not work. In this case, I am getting "This site can’t be reached"

There are lot of articles that I am reading from few days but not getting how to do final setting so that my site start working after I successfully placed all certificate files.

Comment: Is it a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes it is self signed

Comment: Did you enable the `mod_ssl`?  `a2enmod ssl`

Comment: @ivanivanYes I did

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, It is not self signed. My misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Recently Chrome stoped accepting self-signed Certificates. You can save a lot of effort using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) SSL Certificates. They are free, but valid for 90 days only. But you can configure auto renewal process, so  you don't need to worry, because all things happens behind scenes.

Installation on Ubuntu it's simple:

### 1. Add repository to apt

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot`

After complete, update apt-get:

`sudo apt-get update`

### 2. Install Certbot

> Certbot is a client tool for managing certificates from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org).

Run:

`sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache`

### 3. Set up SSL Certificate

`sudo certbot --apache -d sitename.com`

If your domain could be accessed with *www* prefix run this command instead:

`sudo certbot --apache -d sitename.com -d www.sitename.com`

From now Certbot will run automatically via /etc/cron.d to check for expiring certificates.

You can validate process by running:

`sudo certbot renew --dry-run`.

It's done.

Full documentation for Certbot is here: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/

Comment: You do not need to add a new PPA to use LE.  A simple `apt-get install letsencrypt` does it for you...

Comment: My certificate is not self signed so shall I follow same procedure for real certificate as well?

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 16.04  this link may be useful when renewing certificates:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/997402/problem-installing-certificates-with-letsencrypt